# What is wrong with defining all the streams needed for an application at the root widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

What are the negatives to setting up streams for all the data I would need throughout my application with a MultiProvider in the root widget of the application and then using Provider.Of(context) to retrieve them in child widgets in the future?

If this question is way off the mark or I am misunderstanding some major principle behind this, please help me to understand as I am obviously new to this!

Answer (score 0):

If you use this method, some providers which depend if data is available in other provider may not work.

For example you want to see if the user has an account record or not. If he doesnt have an account he will go to a profile form, and if he has an account he can see all his purchases stored in a nested collection. It will not be possible to do with multiproviders.

Except these I dont think there is any other problem.